# Installing "LowRankQP" R-package results in an error

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I tried to install the R package "LowRankQP" on my Mac (Intel processor). However, this resulted in an error, the package had non-zero exit status.

Since the package has been removed from CRAN, I went to the archive (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/LowRankQP/) and downloaded the file "LowRankQP_1.0.5.tar.gz". After that I tried to install the package via `install.packages("/path/to/file", type="source", repos=NULL)`. But this resulted in the following warning/error message:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
> ld: library not found for -lgfortran
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [LowRankQP.so] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘LowRankQP’
> removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/LowRankQP’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘/Users/xxx/Downloads/LowRankQP_1.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Do you have any idea what the problem is or how I can install the package successfully? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the MacOS toolchain for compiling source code (Fortran, C/C++, etc.)

I think you only need to install Xcode to resolve this particular problem. But the easiest way to get your entire toolchain sorted is probably with the new macrtools package: https://mac.thecoatlessprofessor.com/macrtools/

Comment: Thank you, this hint helped me. I installed the GNU Fortran compiler and after that I was able to install the package.